# Erro ao chamar tela pelo botao

Tags: android-activity, syntax-error, tela

Erro no botão, simplesmente fecha o aplicativo no emulador quando aperta para abrir outra activity, já veio todo mundo pra tentar resolver e nada, segue o LogCat e as classes ( o problema esta no btnCadastro ) :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     Button btnCadastro,button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnCadastro= findViewById(R.id.btnCadastro);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OCadastro.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

        btnCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OCadastro.class);
                    startActivity(it);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*

> 05-17 14:17:58.695 17020-17020/a.senai.login_campsell3
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: a.senai.login_campsell3, PID: 17020
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{a.senai.login_campsell3/a.senai.login_campsell3.OCadastro}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                at a.senai.login_campsell3.OCadastro.onCreate(OCadastro.java:25)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)